# Mockolate: dispatch binding events?

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, binding, mockolate

Is it possible to ask Mockolate to dispatch binding events?

For example, given this class:

```
class Person {
    [Bindable]
    public var name:String;
}
```

I'd like the mock:

```
var mockPerson:Person = nice(Person);
```

To dispatch a `propertyChangeEvent` when the `name` field is change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned Binding events are instances of `PropertyChangeEvent`, just create an instance using `PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent()` and use that with `.dispatches()`.

Like so:

```
mock(person).setter("name").arg(anything())
    .dispatches(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(person, "name", oldValue, newValue));
```

Note however that the `oldValue` and `newValue` will need to be supplied.

I see merit in making a shortcut for this scenario seeing as binding is heavily used. The only tricky part is keeping the previous value.

If you wanted to tackle implementing this yourself I suggest looking at the `Answer` and `Decorator` classes and subclasses.